# How to prove that a graph does not have a block graph that is $C_n$ $n\geq 4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The block graph of a given graph $G$ is the intersection graph of its blocks. Thus, it has one vertex for each block of $G$, and an edge between two vertices whenever the corresponding two blocks share a vertex. A biconnected component (sometimes known as a 2-connected component or block) is a maximal biconnected subgraph. The blocks are attached to each other at shared vertices called cut vertices or articulation points. Specifically, a cut vertex is any vertex whose removal increases the number of connected components. I know that a graph block can be a $C_3$ such as the graph block of a $S_3$ (Star graph) also know as $K_{1,k}$ (Complete bipartite)

Comment: if the block graph had a cycle, the blocks that correspond to the nodes of that cycle would actually be one larger block (their intersections would not be articulation points).

Comment: @JimN For that to work out, we need to define something slightly different from the block graph: a graph whose vertices correspond to blocks and cut vertices, with an edge from each cut vertex to the block it's in. In this definition, a cycle might happen from having many overlapping blocks.

Comment: And actually in this definition I think the statement is not true: doesn't an $n$-edge star graph have a block graph of $K_n$, which has many long cycles?

Comment: $C_n$-free means no induced $C_n$. The only induced cycles in $K_n$ are triangles

Comment: Sorry, I already edited the title it wasn't that **have** a $C_n$ $n\geq 4$, but that **it isn't** a $C_n$ $n\geq 4$

Answer (score 1):

Assume the block graph of $G$ has some cycle > 4. Choose an edge $xy$ in the cycle. Note that $x$ and $y$ are nodes that are connected by a path in the cycle which does not use edge $xy$.

So $x$ and $y$ each correspond to two blocks of $G$, which intersect, and their intersection should be an articulation point. Remove that vertex -- this should disconnect the graph, and in particular, disconnect a vertex in block $x$ from a vertex in block $y$. But now there is another path which connects the vertices of $x$ with the vertices of $y$ through the other path in the cycle.

This argument breaks down when the articulation point removed belongs to all blocks (as in your triangle case).